# Why use redux-persist over manually persisting state to localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

Another way to ask would be, if you really only want to start your app up with the data saved in localStorage (rehydrate) and save every redux state change to localStorage (persist) is using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) any better than using your own solution like [Dan Abramov explains here](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage)?

I understand redux-persist comes with a lot of other features, and I myself started using it to be able to use redux-persist-crosstab (to be able to deal with changes between apps running in different tabs), but I wonder if it's overkill to use it for the most basic scenario. Especially since it's harder to understand and sometimes does funny stuff, like calling `persist/REHYDRATE` randomly.

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The usage of `redux-persist` depends upon the use case of the application.

First, let me highlight some of the main features of `redux-persist`

- Usage of [PersistGate](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md) which automatically provides a delay in `rendering of the components` until the state gets `persisted` along with the usage to show the `loading` component.
- Custom functions to persist based on multiple types such as  `persistStore`, `persistReducer` and `persistObject`
- `AutoMerging` of the `initialStates` from the different states based on `shallow` and `deep` levels
- Probably the most important feature of `blacklisting` and `whitelisting` the `reducers`
- Nested Persistence for `shallow` level `persistence` and `deep` level `persistence`
- Persisting with `migrations` to store different versions of the `redux-store`.
- Transforms to support *immutable*, *compression*, *encrypt*, *filter*, etc.

Considering the `application` you build is just for `development` purposes, then it would require at most `PersistGate`, `persistStore` and probably `blacklist` and `whitelist` of the reducers, which would still be **considerable amount of work** *considering that you are aware what you might need for your application*.

Now for the applications that are `production` level and are prone to scaling, then it would be requiring at least `5 / 7` features that I have listed above. Without this module you might need to install modules for *compression*, *encryption* and much more, find a way to gracefully store different versions of the `redux-store` and `retrieve` and `display` what might fit your requirement, along with the `rehydration` of that `redux-store` state.

There are many more implications to this, which will be encountered later on. Therefore based on the requirements of the project, I think it would be beneficial to use this package, to manage the `redux-store storage`